# How do I erase the background of a field when the user types something?

Tags: javascript

I have a search field which basically gives the user a "tip" of what to search (which is the  background image). I need to erase the background when he types something. But I'm not sure how.

This is the searchfield:

```
<input style="font-size:20px; width:300px; color: #444; background: url('http://chusmix.com/Imagenes/busca.png') white;" type="text" id="s"  name="s" onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.style.background='url(http://chusmix.com/Imagenes/busca.png) no-repeat 0% 50% white';}">
```

Is there an easy way to do it? If you need more info please ask. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this little bit of javascript in the tag: onFocus='this.value=""';

Comment: Thanks, I was using that before. But now I want to erase the background when the user types something. Not when he focuses.

Comment: Your best bet is this answer if I'm honest, the other callbacks (without using jQuery) don't register keypresses very well

Comment: The thing is. The field autofocuses so the user has no idea what to do it I don't do it with keypresses.

Comment: I finally could do it with onKeyUp I didn't know about it.Thanks

Comment: MY solution is using onKeyUp and works in the browsers I have tested. This answer does not answer your actual question...

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to get rid of the `onblur` and instead make it `onfocus` (so the background changes when they enter the box).. or  even `onchange` so whenever they type it goes away.

Comment: if it was onchange it wouldn't immediately update until the field registers a change

Answer (score 0):

I am using Facebook like plugin from here

http://github.com/loopj/jQuery-Tokenizing-Autocomplete-Plugin

I just had a go at this one and it was really easy to implement using an asp.net page to output the **JSON** (from the search params) Then theres just a few lines of Javascript you need to create it (and the settings)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#Users").tokenInput("../Services/Job/UnassignedUsers.aspx?p=<%= projectID %>&j=<%= jobID %>", {
        hintText: "Begin typing the user name of the person you wish to assign.",
        noResultsText: "No results",
        searchingText: "Searching..."
    });
});
```

**Hope this might help you**

Answer (score 0):

Assume txtTopSearchBox is the id of text box and "Search" is the content on that (tip)

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#txtTopSearchBox").focus(function() {
        $(this).removeClass().addClass("txtSearchBoxFocus").val("");

```
});
$("#txtTopSearchBox").blur(function() {
    if (($(this).val() == "Search") || ($(this).val() == "")) {
        $(this).removeClass().addClass("txtSearchBox").val("Search");
    }
});

$("#txtTopSearchBox").keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {

        var key = $("#txtTopSearchBox").val();
        key = escape(key);
        window.location.href = "browse.aspx?search=" + key;
        return false;
    }
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in html5, the upcoming [placeholder attribute](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-placeholder-attribute) will take care of this. But alas, not all browsers are html5 ready. The second sub-heading on [this page](http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html#placeholder) shows browser compatibility.

Until then, the JavaScript method PMV describes works well.

Answer (score 0):

Tested and works in Fx 3.6, Safari 5 and Chrome. Image too big for field when not copying the attributes to the withoutTip too

```
<style type="text/css">
.withTip { 
  font-size:20px; 
  width:300px; 
  color: #444; 
  background: white url(http://chusmix.com/Imagenes/busca.png) }
.withoutTip { background: white url()} 
</style>

<input class="withTip" type="text" id="s"  name="s" 
onkeyup="this.className=(this.value=='')?'withTip':'withoutTip'" />
```

or

```
<style type="text/css">
#s {font-size:20px; width:300px; color: #444;}
.withTip { background: white url(http://chusmix.com/Imagenes/busca.png) }
.withoutTip { background: white url()} 
</style>
```

Comment: I thought it would the solution but it didn't work, It just remains blank no matter what. I tried incorporating it to my searchbox and it didn't work. Then I simply copied pasted it and it didn't work either. Not sure why

Comment: Works for me in FX 3.6 for Mac, for Safari 5 and in Chrome... Not sure what your issue is. Only problem is the image is larger than the field is without the image. I cannot test IE until tomorrow